# How to uncheck the Checkbox on removing the Item in Android?

Tags: android, list, listview

In My Apps, On Clicking the Remove Button, Items will get removed in the Ordering page.. But, removed Item should be unchecked in the ListView also.. Please help me to uncheck the removed Items..

I Tried and This is my Code:

```
       public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {


      final  ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selecteditemlistview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textViewSelectedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedtext);
            holder.price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemprice);
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemimage);
            holder.qty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectqty);
            holder.total=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);               
            holder.delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            holder.uncheck = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String amount=holder.qty.getText().toString();
        final Double price1=Double.parseDouble(itemprice.get(position));
        int qut=Integer.parseInt(holder.qty.getText().toString());
        Double total=(price1*qut);
        holder.textViewSelectedText.setText(arr1.get(position));
        holder.price.setText(itemprice.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(itemimage.get(position));
        holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(total));


        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 arr1.remove(position);
                 itemimage.remove(position);
                 itemprice.remove(position);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                 holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);
            }

        });
```

Thanks in Advance.

This is My Logcat:

```
      05-19 12:10:17.355: D/AndroidRuntime(721): Shutting down VM
      05-19 12:10:17.365: W/dalvikvm(721): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721): java.lang.NullPointerException
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at com.customer.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:114)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
      05-19 12:10:17.375: E/AndroidRuntime(721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the statement in line 114 of CustomAdapter.java?

Comment: holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);

Comment: I am not able to solve it., Help me to solve

Comment: One advice: if you are new to Android, don't use HolderPattern or other optimizations - just stick with the simple ListView as it is and learn it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the following lines:

```
             notifyDataSetChanged();
             holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);
```

to

```
             holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Can you replace `holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);` with the following code?

    `View parent    = (View)v.getParent();
    CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)parent.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);
    if(null != chkBox){
        chkBox.setChecked(false);
    }`

Comment: I replaced the code but no changes,. After removing the Item still the checkbox is Checked.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: u can first clear your list then add again .hope its helpful to you.

Comment: No in your activity where u set adapter.